# How can I get the filename using $_REQUEST with the blueimp upload code

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the filename of the file that is uploaded with blueimp.

This is in my network tab:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqfBsJR1e0o6dxmsx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="199370898.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

So I tried it like this:

```
$filename = $_REQUEST['files'];
```

Or like this:

```
$filename = $_REQUEST['filename'];
```

But they are both empty.

This however which is in the same post:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqfBsJR1e0o6dxmsx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cat_id"

85
```

And

```
$catid = $_REQUEST['cat_id'];
```

Shows me 85 fine.

Why?

Comment: use $_FILES for acces to uploaded files

Answer (score 1):

Access to file name:

```
$_FILES['files']['name'][0]
```

More information: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @IncredibleHat You are absolutely right, thanks. Corrected

Answer (score 0):

Debug is a good option, try to print te request with: `print_r($_REQUEST);` and you cant see the vars.

Comment: sorry, is  "... and see the vars."